# Windows UIAutomatin in C language

Tags: c++, c, microsoft-ui-automation

I have written a c++ program by using UIAutomation on windows. The libraries I have used are **windows.h** and **Uiautomation.h**. It works well. However, I want to convert the program to C program. (There is no classes). When I try to do it, I have taken an error which is **error: unknown type name 'IUIAutomationElement'**. Even file included libraries are enough in the cpp program, why the C version does not run?
Thank you...

Comment: ... because not all C++ code is valid C?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I know that.Probably you misunderstood the question or I would not ask well.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look into [Microsoft doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement), it is clear that `IUIAutomationElement` element is a C++ class and cannot be directly used from a C program. Your own code can be plain C, but you will have to use an wrapper module in C++ that declares some `extern "C"` functions. They will be callable from C and will be able to use `IUIAutomationElement`.